# List subfolders of folders which are written in file

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I got a folder `/srv/log/` on a Linux server where I have subfolders with the server names:

server1 server2 server3 server4

I need a command which will show me what is inside of those folders, but only specific ones which i have in text file "del_list":

```
server2 
server4
```

I am trying to use a loop:

```sh
for i in `cat del_list`; do `ls /srv/log/$i/`; done
```

but it shows me only part of those servers and error:

```
-bash: folder1: command not found
-bash: folder2: command not found
```

but there are many other folders:'folder2, folder3' there. But I cannot list them using my command, what did I do wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in `cat del_list`; do ls /srv/log/$i/; done
```

without the backtick around the command after the `do`

Comment: Still [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: This is solution I was looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can run a python scrpit:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
import subprocess
import os

with open("del_list", "r") as f:
    data = f.read().split(" ")
    
    for file in data:
        filepath = "/srv/log/" + file
        if os.path.isdir(filepath):
            subprocess.check_call("ls " + filepath, shell=True)
        else:
            print("Path " + filepath + " not exist!")
```

Answer (score 1):

With a recent bash:

```sh
mapfile -t < del_list
ls "${MAPFILE[@]/#//srv/logs/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

> am trying to use a loop: for i in `cat del_list`; do `ls /srv/log/$i/`; done

[Don't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

With `find` and `grep`

```
find /srv/logs -type d | grep -Ff del_list
```

Now to save the output in an array using `mapfile` which is a `bash4+` feature.

```
mapfile -t array < <(find /srv/logs -type d | grep -Ff del_list)
```

---

Now you can use `ls` for interactive use.

```
ls "${array[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do something with the matches and not just print them, probably loop over them:

```sh
while IFS= read -r folder; do
    for file in "$folder"/*; do
        : something with "$file"
    done
done <del_list
```

To just run a single command, you can avoid the inner loop:

```sh
while IFS= read -r folder; do
   ls "$folder"/*
done <del_list
```

(though generally [don't use `ls` in scripts.)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

This is portable to Bourne `sh` / POSIX shell, and a very basic shell programming idiom.

The `IFS=` is useful to prevent the shell from breaking up significant whitespace.  The `-r` option to `read` is useful to disable the peculiar processing of backslashes which was implemented in the `read` command in the original Bourne shell, and kept in POSIX for reasons of backwards compatibility. And, as always, you want to [quote variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) unless you specifically require the shell to perform word splitting and wildcard expansion on the values.